# Get Logs from another class to set this Text to a TextView

Tags: java, android, logging, system.out

I am using one MainActivity and another .java which includes a class.

I want to be able to set the Logs or System.out from my excluded class in a textView inside my  MainActivity.

For example the System.out from this method inside my class:

```
private class Util {

private static KNXNetworkLinkIP connect(InetSocketAddress isaLocalEP, InetSocketAddress isaRemoteEP)
  {
    KNXNetworkLinkIP netLinkIp = null;

    int serviceMode = KNXNetworkLinkIP.TUNNEL; // tunnel to IP router
    boolean useNAT = true; // NAT not used for PC true or false , but needed for emulator = true
    KNXMediumSettings tpSettings = new TPSettings(true); // TP1 medium

    try
    {
      // Output the local end point address

      if (m_debugOutput == true)
      {

        System.out.println("..Tunneling, NAT ignored, TP1 medium");

        // Should be the PC's VPN address

        System.out.print("..Local  EP:");
        System.out.println(isaLocalEP.getHostName() + ":" + isaLocalEP.getPort());

        System.out.print("..Remote EP:");
        System.out.println(isaRemoteEP.getHostName() + ":" + isaRemoteEP.getPort());

        System.out.print("..useNAT:");
        System.out.println(useNAT);

        System.out.println();
      }

      netLinkIp = new KNXNetworkLinkIP(serviceMode, isaLocalEP, isaRemoteEP, useNAT, tpSettings);
    }
    catch (KNXLinkClosedException e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:KNXLinkClosedException = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (KNXFormatException e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:KNXFormatException = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (KNXException e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:KNXException = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:Exception = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return netLinkIp;

  } // connect(isaLocalEP, isaRemoteEP)

}
```

I know this is a simple question but I am stucked and do not know how to realize it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either log using `Log.x()` methods and then read system logs, grep to obtain just yours and display, or write own logger that would put your logs into i.e. database and then your other code could fetch and display it.